# Adding vbs yes/no box code to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to add the following yes/no box into a batch file but keep failing.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

intMessage = Msgbox("Would you like to go to URL?", _
    vbYesNo, "Click yes to go to URL")

If intMessage = vbYes Then
    objShell.Run("http://www.url.com")
Else
    Wscript.Quit
End If
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: What does "keep failing" mean? How *specifically*  is it "failing"? The code you show is not for a batch file; it's VBScript code, and needs to be run with `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`. It won't work in a batch file.

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain myself. I understand this is vbs code, but would like to include this within my .bat file. I have tried parsing the vbs code from within the .bat file into a temp file. Example of one line `code` echo Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") > %tmp%\MMGu_tmp.vbs

Comment: That's  not the question you asked here. Please [edit] your question to ask what you *really mean to ask*, instead of burying it in the comments. If people can't understand the question, they can't possibly help you find a solution. (I don't really understand how that counts as "adding it into a batch file". )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off

    call :MsgBox "Would you like to go to URL?"  "VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "Click yes to go to URL"
    if errorlevel 7 (
        echo NO - don't go to the url
    ) else if errorlevel 6 (
        echo YES - go to the url
        start "" "http://www.google.com"
    )

    exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
    >"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
    set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Answer (score 2):

Although there are several methods to include vbs code into a Batch file, all of them are clumsy, but you may [google for they](https://www.google.com.mx/#q=vbscript%20code%20in%20batch%20file&safe=off) if you want.

May I suggest a different solution?

The inclusion of JScript code into a Batch file is simpler than VBScript, and the translation of a small code segment from VBS to JScript is not problematic. For example:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
rem Execute the JScript code:
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript code start here

objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f.aspx
intMessage = objShell.Popup("Would you like to go to URL?",0,"Click yes to go to URL",4) 

if (intMessage == 6) 
    objShell.Run("http://www.url.com")
else
    WScript.Quit()
//endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and the proposed JScript version. I have not worked much with JScript and will look more into this @Aacini

Answer (score 2):

I found this code on the Net, perhaps it can help you !

```
::'.@FILE: .@This: NTFunID031.cmd @Date: 2014-04-17 .@Note: NTMaxToolsPlay ID 031
::'.@SUMMARY: .@Note: cmd+vbs, all in one  .@INFO: .@File: NTFunID031_readme.txt
::'.@PROJECT_NAME: .@Parent: NTMaxTools .@AUTHOR: .@Name: NT 
::'.
::'.
::response= MsgBox("Are you okay ?", vbYesNo+vbQuestion, "Hello ! ;)")
rem assign response to exit code
::wscript.quit(response)
call break '& @echo off& cls& echo.& echo.
call break '& title : -- Real all in one [cmd+vbs], NTMaxToolsPlay, just for the fun ;)
call break '& echo Hi!
call break '& wscript //e:vbs //nologo "%~f0"
call break '& set /a rep=%errorlevel%
call break '& if %rep% equ 6 echo Yesssssssssss, me too :p
call break '& if %rep% equ 7 echo Oh Nonnn :'(
call break '& echo.& pause
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I may actually use this with further testing @Hackoo